# How to count symbol instead of string length with Fish?

Tags: string, fish, ansi-colors

In a discussion on a [pull request for pure theme for fish](https://github.com/rafaelrinaldi/pure/pull/68#discussion_r239634119) we are wondering how to count the number of symbols instead of the string length.

Doing such will allow to refactor our code in a more elegant/maintenable/testable way.

```
❯ set -l down_arrow "⇣"
❯ string length $down_arrow
1

❯ set -l down_arrow_red (set_color red)"⇣"(set_color normal)
❯ string length $down_arrow_red
15
```

#### Question

On the second string we get `15` but what we care about is that we got one glyph (e.g. `⇣`) not all the coloring syntax.

How can we get that with fish?

Answer (score 0):

One possible [solution using `sed`](https://superuser.com/a/380778/174465) is to pipe our variable through this command:

```
sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g'
```

As

```
❯ echo $user_and_host | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' | string length
11
```

#### Test

```
❯ set -l user (set_color red)root
❯ set -l at (set_color grey)@
❯ set -l host (set_color blue)remote
❯ set user_and_host "$user$at$host"

❯ echo $user_and_host
root@remote  
❯ string length $user_and_host
26  # should be 11
```